# Importing Concrete5 content to WordPress

Tags: database, mysql, import, migration

Are there any tools out there to convert content from a Concrete5 database to something WordPress can use? I have a client that may switch over, and would like to avoid manually copying content over if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to WordPress's **Tools » Import** page in your site's Admin section (eg, `http://example.com/wp-admin`), you'll find that it can import, among other things, HTML pages.  So if you have a way to export your Concrete5 site to a directory of HTML pages, you should be able to import them that way.

Comment: I've never used Concrete5 so I'll take a look and see what can be done.